# com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We are having severe problems connecting to any of our databases in Cloud SQL with a wide range of errors (from delays in retrieving results) to exceptions on the google driver:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>Sorry...</title><style> body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style></head><body><div><table><tr><td><b><font face=times color=#0039b6 size=10>G</font><font face=times color=#c41200 size=10>o</font><font face=times color=#f3c518 size=10>o</font><font face=times color=#0039b6 size=10>g</font><font face=times color=#30a72f size=10>l</font><font face=times color=#c41200 size=10>e</font></b></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">Sorry...</div></td></tr></table></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;"><h1>We're sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.</p></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;">See <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div><div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">&copy; 2013 Google - <a href="https://www.google.com">Google Home</a></div></body></html>
    com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:861)
    com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi$DefaultGoogleApi.execImpl(RpcGoogleApi.java:326)
    com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi$DefaultGoogleApi.exec(RpcGoogleApi.java:308)
    com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.openConnection(RpcGoogleApi.java:99)
    com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:58)
    com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:66)
    com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.connectImpl(Driver.java:109)
    com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:98)
    com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:31)
    org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnect
```

Or:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: 502 Bad Gateway
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:80)
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:146)
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:351)
```

It was working perfectly until an hour ago which we started to get alerts with the failures.

Best regards
Sergio

Comment: Did you check system health status on Google dashboard? What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Between 11.00PST and 11.30PST there was an issue that interrupted many Cloud SQL instances. The problem should now be resolved.

We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority for the Google Cloud Platform, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better.

To be kept informed of other Google Cloud SQL issues and launches, please join google-cloud-sql-announce@googlegroups.com

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-announce